# Alternative to "tree" command or a way to reduce tree output file size?

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, tree, treeview

I want to do a "tree" output file on a lot of clients but in general i found that the file size lands around 100mb.

This is WAY to big so i wanted to ask if there is any alternative way or command to do it or any way to reduce the file size?

I want to create a HDD catalog file log for later review and to be able to do some statistics with the files.

Comment: tree generates a text file, I mean, if you want to record each file on your hard disk, if the number of files/dirs is there, I don't think another tool can reduce the size of the output file dramatically. However, you can try to compress the result file

Answer (score 2):

For simulate the `$ tree` command when you are in a directory, you can use also this command:

```
$ ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//──/g' -e 's/─/├/' -e '$s/├/└/'
```

Then you have a result similar to the output of `$ tree` command